# Connecting to an Oracle Database using the Visual Studio 2012 Data Connections tool

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Database using the Visual Studio 2012 Data Connections tool. I'm getting the ORA-12154 error: "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified". I need to use a port and a service name.

I've tried following patterns:

- servername:port/servicename
- servername:port\servicename
- servername:port:servicename

with no positive result.

I've tried also the "Omit Oracle Connection" property in advanced settings also with no positive result.

I'm using the .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection string should look like this

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=portnumber))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service)))
```

A problem might be 128 chars restriction on connection string length but we can handle it by defining hostname in hosts with for instance one letter.